# Some-size some-colour square in background of div without resizing div or editing html

Tags: css

I have a div spanning the whole height of the viewport, while being horizontally center-aligned through use of margins, and would like to center a red square of, say, a 100px by 100px in that div just using CSS. Background-color: red wouldn't work, because that will span the whole div, which will be bigger than 100 pixels. I currently have the following solution:

```
div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, red);
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

It works, because there's no shift in gradient, but using linear-gradient in this way seems sort of hackish, which makes the solution less useable. Is there any way to generate a purely red square of some size smaller than the div without resorting editing the HTML of the page, or resizing the div with CSS? Preferably, I would also like to avoid scaling up an image of 1 red pixel (I wouldn't easily be able to change the colour).

Thanks for reading!

Comment: depending on what content is in the div, you could maybe play with `margins` of a `div` inside a `div`

Comment: Looks like I was wrong about the dimensions of the div. It has a 100% height, but the width is already limited through margins, so this won't work. I will update the info in the text.

Comment: What about putting a div with absolute positioning, and then position it relative to the screen with `jQuery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `:after` pseudo selector to add a block with these dimensions. If you position it absolute you can center it using `left`, `top` and a `transform`.

```
.box {
  position: relative;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';  
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
```

}

Or see http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/CbduL

Comment: Perfect! I had to change the pseudo-selector to :before, because otherwise the square wouldn't be in the background, but the foreground. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this
html

```
<body>
    <div id="div0">
        <div id="div1"></hr>
    </div>
</body>
```

css

```
#div1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
   }
 #div0{

    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    background:white;
   }
```